# Mondo Rescue repository unsigned for apt-get

Tags: 14.04, apt, 16.04, backup, ftp

I have been trying to install Mondo Rescue, however, after following the typical instructions:

```
wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/`lsb_release -r|awk '{print $2}'`/mondorescue.sources.list
sudo sh -c "cat mondorescue.sources.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo sh -c "cat >> /etc/apt/preferences << EOF
Package: mindi
Pin: version 2.1.*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mondo
Pin: version 3.0.*
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
"
```

as well as:

```
wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/16.04/mondorescue.pubkey
sudo apt-key add mondorescue.pubkey
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following

```
W: The repository 'ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org//ubuntu 16.04 Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is there some way to fix this or get it working properly?

Answer (score 2):

## Install using built in repository

The [Mondo Rescue Website](http://www.mondorescue.org/downloads.shtml) says manually downloading install files is not needed as it natively available for for Debian/Ubuntu, using:

```
sudo apt-get install mondo
```

However ***THIS IS BROKEN***

The website goes on to say you can download the [repo file](ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/debian/) `mondorescue.sources.list` and add it to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory if you want to use upstream packages.

However ***THIS IS BROKEN***

## Deleted answer one year ago

On December 30, 2016 an answer was posted here and deleted because the user lacked reputation to post a comment. That answer tells us a lot:

> I used to use `mondo` for all Linux data center backups about 10 years
>   ago. However, since then, each release has been spotty on installation
>   for distributions that we use (RHEL, Fedora, CentOS, and Ubuntu). On
>   top of that, I have gotten it to install and work on a VM but fail on
>   the same install on a physical box.
>
> I'm sorry to rant. I miss this fantastic tool. I just don't have the
>   time to debug each piece of the install only to get to the point where
>   I'm managing compilations, repositories, versions, etc. for it to
>   crash or worse, not restore properly...

## One Man Show

On the surface it appears `mondo` development rests primarily on the shoulders of one man: [Bruno Cornec](https://brunocornec.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/mondorescue-3-2-2-is-finally-available/) which is a gigantic feat IMO. Unfortunately it seems time is primarily spent in ***Red Hat Linux*** arena first with UEFI recent support and ***Ubuntu*** not having UEFI support yet. But why woudn't you develop for a paying market place first and a free market place second? Not everyone is a Warehouse Receiver with a good wage by day that can help people in Ubuntu for free by night.

The best summary of problems installing `mondo` in Ubuntu I found was this [Source Forge conversation](https://sourceforge.net/p/mondo/mailman/message/35591945/) between developer and user on January 8, 2017:

> About dependencies : i did not write down all that happened, sorry :-(
>   I  wil install a new vm from scratch later. But at least :
>
> ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/test/ubuntu/16.04/mondorescue-test.sources.list
>   did not work, so I downloaded the packages by hand :
>
> wget \
>   ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/test/ubuntu/16.04/mondo_3.3.0-0.20161223223857.s3640M_amd64.deb
>   \
>   ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/test/ubuntu/16.04/mindi_3.3.0-0.20161223223857.s3640M_amd64.deb
>   \
>   ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/test/ubuntu/16.04/mindi-busybox_1.25.1-1_amd64.deb
>   \
>   ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/test/ubuntu/16.04/libmondorescue-perl_3.3.0-0.20161223223857.s3640M_all.deb
>
> various packages where still missing : from my shell history :
>   - I installed buffer from the Ubuntu repository
>   - I took afio here : ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/16.04/afio_2.5-1_amd64.deb
>   -  ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/14.04/libprojectbuilder-perl_0.14.2-1_all.deb
>   was needed too
>
> and in the logs, I noticed that lzop was needed too (this one I
>   noticed  !) so I installed it by hand as I installed mondo alone the
>   first time with dpkg, it was left broken.

**In the end it was finally installed to backup, but restore didn't work**

## Just the FAQs Ma'am

There is an older [FAQs](http://trac.mondorescue.org/wiki/FAQ#Q11DoesmondoworkwithDebianUbuntudistributions) page from Ubuntu 12.04 era that describes installing `mondo` manually in Ubuntu:

> If you want to use the packages made upstream for Debian or Ubuntu,
>   you need to know that numbering schema are different between upstream
>   mondo (3.0.x) and Ubuntu / Debian packages (1:2.2.x), so you should
>   adapt your /etc/apt/preferences file to avoid updates of mondo with
>   apt-get with older versions. Do the following:

```
wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/`lsb_release -r|awk '{print $2}'`/mondorescue.sources.list
sudo sh -c "cat mondorescue.sources.list >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo sh -c "cat >> /etc/apt/preferences << EOF
Package: mindi
Pin: version 2.1.*
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: mondo
Pin: version 3.0.*
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
"
```

***I would double check these version numbers***

## What can I do to use Mondo?

If you really insist on using Mondo I would contact Bruno in his name link posted above. Offer to test out the install on your Ubuntu system and report back results to get fixes.

Ubuntu 14.04 does have [instructions for installing `mondo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MondoMindi) and these might work in version 16.04. Or at least they might be a better starting point that the other instructions above:

```
cd /tmp
rm *.list
wget ftp://ftp.mondorescue.org/ubuntu/`lsb_release -r|awk '{print $2}'`/mondorescue.sources.list
sudo cp mondorescue.sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mondorescue.sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mondo afio buffer lzop mindi mindi-busybox
sudo ln -s /sbin/parted2fdisk /usr/sbin/parted2fdisk
sudo ln -s /sbin/mke2fs /usr/sbin/mke2fs
```

Now Mondo Archive v3.2.120150305095420-0 is installed, including the required dependencies (afio buffer lzop mindi mindi-busybox)

Then you can run mondo using the following commands:

```
sudo mondoarchive
```

or

```
sudo mondorestore
```

## Other Ask Ubuntu Q&As

These other users have asked questions / stated problems with installing `mondo` recently:

- [Mondo Rescue repository unsigned for apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781970/mondo-rescue-repository-unsigned-for-apt-get)
- [Bootable recovery partition or DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/962597/bootable-recovery-partition-or-dvd)
- [Making an iso backup of my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781738/making-an-iso-backup-of-my-system/781755#781755)

## Summary

For myself I just use `cron` to run a [daily backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917562/backup-linux-configuration-scripts-and-documents-to-gmail/922493#922493) that creates a `.tar` backup file every morning when I boot up. The `.tar` backup file is then e-mailed to my `gmail.com` account and stored in the cloud.

You can simply search `daily backup` for list of options in Ask Ubuntu or google the search term for multiple Linux sites.

I wish my search had yielded more positive results.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package mondo`

Comment: @Paolo Weird. I'll have to investigate this further after work.

Comment: Mondo isn't available for me on Ubuntu 17.10, indeed the [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mondo&searchon=all&suite=all&section=all) website appears to show it's never been part of the default packages.

Comment: @Paolo Today's research updated into answer. I'll update if I find out more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reconsider Mondo Rescue when/if you or anyone else will provide a solution/workaround. In the meantime I'm using veeam, it's easy to install and has hot backup and bare metal restore capabilities.

Comment: @Paolo My concern isn't so much the fact it can't be installed. I worry about that file buried 4 sub-directories deep with a size of 493KB which doesn't get backed up because of it's size and the Epoch seconds are 999999... etc. It's not only the developer it's also the packages it depends on. Mesa just broke Ubuntu LTS a few nights ago: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992571/gui-unity-crashing-in-16-04-lts-after-updates-2018-01-04-compiz-segfaults. Software development requires testing on a lot of platforms. Backups are mission critical apps and you can't see they broke until you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass it, as a work around, by using the following option with `apt-get`:

```
--allow-unauthenticated
```

Otherwise try this:
Author has a problem with GPG geys when moving from DSA to RSA

```
gpg -a --export 8AB63AFD171EFF9E | apt-key add -  
gpg -a --export 6BA8C2D220EBFB0E | apt-key add -
```

Comment: Yep, it's an option; maybe it worth also to mention that `--allow-unauthenticated` is a great security risk.