# how to boot an ubuntu stick installer?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb

I've created the usb installer using the dd program, but now I'm interdict...
it don't run under bios (already selected the usb media in first boot position); so I guess it should be runned under an OS already installed, but I don't know...
anyone that has already solved this situation could be so gentle to answer?

thanks in advance!

edit:
Once refined the process, I've tried to use startup disk creator, but the file(.iso) resulted from genisoimage seems invisible, selected from the folder than clik open and it seems like if i didn't choose the iso...
from genisoimage, "renamed", then used dd, I have a simil filesystem on the usb stik, it consist in folder: boot, cdrom, dev, etc, home, media, opt, root, run, snap, srv, tmp, usr, var... i try to boot in the other pc, but it neither "felt the insert" as said in another canonical page "at the boot: statement press enter"... i guess it was referred at the boot folder created with dd, and could it be the linear process... but no.
In the boot folder, find space folder like: efi, grub and file like: confi000.0_4, config_5.0_4, initr000.0_4, initrd_i.0_4, memte000.bin, memtest88.bin, memtest8.elf, vmlinuz_.0_4 ... in a moment of crazycrakking I've tried to unfolder the boot folder in the usb stick, but neither gentle, nor "sudoing".

Comment: Welcome! You don't need an OS for it to run. Could you share the exact command you used to create the usb? *"it don't run under bios "* could you explain this with more detail?

Comment: Hi, the commands for the iso are:

genisoimage -input-charset UTF-8 -allow-limited-size -o /pathtowherewillbethe/filename.iso --exclude=/proc(and lost+found, mnt, sys) /
While, for the usb stick installer: sudo dd if=/pathtothe/filename.iso of=/pathtousb/sdecc... conv=fdatasync status=progress

And the bios with the usb first boot settings are ignored and the pc proceed directly to the run of the operative system already installed, so it is as the settings are HDD for the first boot

Comment: You haven't said what ISO you are trying to write (there are a number of types and methods vary on type). All Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu will work with these instructions - https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016  If you're talking about a non-Ubuntu ISO you're off-topic and instructions may differ.

Comment: Perhaps easier to try an bootable USB creator like Etcher, Rufus or UNetbootin if you are on Windows or Etcher, mkusb or Startup Disk Creator if you are on Linux.

Comment: edited for news, help please

Comment: If you're not trying to just create a bootable USB from a downlloaded ISO but are trying to create the ISO from a running system -- see https://askubuntu.com/questions/534210/how-to-create-an-iso-from-current-installation